# PHP Saving a varible within a script

Tags: php

Hey This might already have been asked, but Is their a way to save a variable within the script So that next time you reopen a page, Your "Progress" would have been saved?

here a bit of code???

```
<script>
    var number = 0;
    number = (number + 1);
</script>
```

After that ^^^ 
Is it possible to save the new variable ('number') so that next time the script is run it would have been saved?

Thanks for your help....

Comment: You could save it in a cookie or database.

Comment: Or you could save it in a session

Comment: What about Gobal variables?